# SSL and Umbraco

Tags: windows, ssl, umbraco

I am trying to get SSL working on a Windows server that is hosting our Umbraco sites. We have numerous sites all working within the same Umbraco installation and I have done the binding of the main domain to the SSL certificate on the server and set umbracoUseSSL to true. I have also added the domain with the https part to the culture and hostnames in umbraco.

The above is not working when I type my domain with the https?

My question is since I have not placed a UrlReWrite redirect from http to https is this the reason why I cannot see my website with the https or is it to do with something else?

Comment: Is this IIS? Is SSL set up in IIS Manager (click on the website note then 'Bindings' in the right-hand side bar, under 'Edit Site')? If it is, can you view non-Umbraco pages over SSL, i.e. is this an Umbraco problem or an IIS problem?

Comment: The server required a full restart and not just IIS, appreciate your help Rup.